# Trying to build Google Map on ReactNative IOS emulator but Error occured

Tags: ios, google-maps, react-native, frontend, xcode10.1

I've been trying to build google maps on my ios React Native emulator but an error appeared saying that AIRrgooglemap dir must be added to Xcode which it has.

I researched ways to make it work such as this link https://cuneyt.aliustaoglu.biz/en/using-google-maps-as-provider-in-ios-with-react-native/ and others and started implementing and changing files on Xcode with no results. Below are the errors seen in React Native IOS emulator and Xcode build

React Native IOS error:

[[image: React Native IOS error[1]]

Xcode Error:

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your question on iOS, I checked the relevant documentation, there should be some steps missing, I suggest you use the following steps:

1.`npm install react-native-maps --save`

2.`react-native link react-native-maps`

3.Download the [GoogleMaps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start) library, copy it to the ios folder, and link the framework and configuration .bundle resources in Xcode as shown.

[image]
   [image]

4.Configure the package.json file.

```
 "scripts":{
"start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
"postinstall": "./node_modules/react-native-maps/enable-google-maps 'ios/GoogleMaps-3.1.0/**'", },
```

5.npm install

6.Configure the code in AppDelegate.m.

[image]

7.Write the react-native code.

[image]

I made a [sample](https://github.com/12star9/rn-cli/releases) project myself, you can refer to release v0.0.1.

Comment: Hi star, thanks for replying, I have actually solved this long ago. I will still give you that thumbs up for your effort. cheers